# Communication between process in c with message queue

Tags: c, message-queue, concurrent-processing

this would be a basic version of what the project will be. I have X user that generate transaction handled by a father. Then, I've tried to establish a connection with a message queue between father and child but when i launch process child with execve it doesn't create the message and the father stuck. If i run a user(child) while father is going it will fill queue with the message and the father catch it and print with an error of memory crashed. How can i optimize the communication??this is a whole new argument for me and i'm very noob in C. (i went from Java). i hope my purpose will sounds clear to you, in order to receive as many suggestion possible to achive my tasks. Thanks.

**UPDATE**: child and parent communicate but:

> -if i wanna use shared memory to define a variable x as id for the queue the parent stuck and don't do anything.
>
> -if i put a printf of an argument og argv in child (example: when i pass the id by the parent). The child will print nothing except for
> other printf defined after that
>
> -The communicarion work but give me: stack smashing detected. I searched and found out that there would be a segmention fault, but i
> can't find where.Is it right? erro at line 54: after return, is it possible?

**Parent**

```
#include "config.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char * args[2] = {CHILD_NAME,NULL};
    int q_id,num_bytes;
    struct msgUser mt_msg;

#ifndef SO_USERS_NUM
    printf("Error in main:  SO_USERS_NUM not defined");
#endif
    /* 
        Creation users, main do forks as SO_USERS_NUM is setting on confing library.
        A child do a execve to the same file .c with the required operation.
        args: array of string that contains data usefull to user
    */
    q_id = msgget(KEY_QUEUE, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    for (int i = 0; i < SO_USERS_NUM; i++)
    {
        switch (fork())
        {
        case 0:
#ifdef CHILD_NAME            
            execve(CHILD_NAME,args,NULL);
#endif
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            break;
         case -1:
            printf("Error in main:  forkkodio");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
     for (int i = 0; i < SO_USERS_NUM; i++)
        {
            printf("Ho finito di aspettare:%d  sono il padre: %d\n",wait(NULL),getppid());
        }
    
    while (1) {
        /* now receiving the message */
        num_bytes = msgrcv(q_id, &mt_msg, 120, 3, 0);

        if (num_bytes >= 0) {
            /* received a good message (possibly of zero length) */
            printf("messaggio ricevuto: %d \n",mt_msg.numero);
            break;
        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Child:**

```
#include "user_manager.h"
#include "config.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    //printf("\n user id: %0x",atoi(argv[1]));
  
    int q_id;
    struct msgUser my_msg;

    q_id = msgget(KEY_QUEUE, IPC_CREAT | 0600);
    my_msg.mtype = 3;
    my_msg.numero = 33;
    
    msgsnd(q_id, &my_msg, 120, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

**config.h:**

```
#ifndef _CONFIG_H_
#define _CONFIG_H_
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

struct msgUser {
    long mtype;             /* message type, must be > 0 */
    int numero;
};
/*
    KEY_QUEUE define the start key for the master process.
    Children nodes will increase this value to create owner's queue
*/
#define KEY_QUEUE 0x200800                     
/*
   CHILD_NAME name of users's code lauched by execve
*/
#define CHILD_NAME "user"
/*
   SO_USERS_NUM define the maximum number of users
*/
#define SO_USERS_NUM 1
/*
   SO_NODES_NUM define the maximum number of nodes
*/
#define SO_NODES_NUM 10
/*
    SO_BUDGET_INIT initial budget of each user
*/
#define SO_BUDGET_INIT 1000
/*
    SO_REWARD the percentage of reward paid by each user for processing a transaction
*/
#define SO_REWARD 5 
/*
    SO_MIN_TRANS_GEN_NSEC minimum value of time (expressed in nano-seconds)     
    that elapses between the generation of a transaction and the next by a user
*/
#define SO_MIN_TRANS_GEN_NSEC 1000
/*
    SO_MAX_TRANS_GEN_NSEC maximum value of time (expressed in nano-seconds)     
    that elapses between the generation of a transaction and the next by a user
*/
#define SO_MAX_TRANS_GEN_NSEC 3000
/*
    SO_RETRY maximum value of failure by an user to start a transaction.
*/
#define SO_RETRY 3
/*
    SO_TP_SIZE number of transaction in the same node in the same time
*/
#define SO_TP_SIZE 6
/*
    SO_MIN_TRANS_PROC_NSEC minimun time for node to elaborate a transaction block
*/
#define SO_MIN_TRANS_PROC_NSEC 1000
/*
    SO_MAX_TRANS_PROC_NSEC maximum time for node to elaborate a transaction block
*/
#define SO_MAX_TRANS_PROC_NSEC 3000
/*
    SO_SIM_SEC simulation's duration
*/
#define SO_SIM_SEC 120
/*
    SO_NUM_FRIENDS node's friends
*/
#define SO_NUM_FRIENDS 3
/*
    SO_HOPS maximum nuber of transaction forward to a friend before the master create a new node.
*/
#define SO_HOPS 5
/*
    SO_REGISTRY_SIZE maximun number of blocks processed by master
*/
#define SO_REGISTRY_SIZE 3
/*
    SO_BLOCK_SIZE number of a transaction in a block
*/
#define SO_BLOCK_SIZE 3

/*
    defined set of generic function's master
*/


#endif
```

Comment: It seems like you are confusing msg and shm.

Comment: My idea is to uso shm to share a the queue's key but, for now, it's only a try. I want that a child can send a msg to the father, because i at the end i will exange message between children only. If chil-father it's not possible i'll do directly child-child

Comment: Strip down your PoC, and (maybe) make it work. After that you could make things more complex, adding layers of abstaction or indirection.

Comment: Forget the `shm*` calls (for now). In parent _before_ the `fork` do: `q_id = msgget(IPC_PRIVATE, IPC_CREAT | 0600);` Then just use `q_id` with `msgsnd/msgrcv` after the `fork` The id will be inherited by the child and just work

Comment: What is the rationale for the [magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Unnamed_numerical_constants) `120` as the *msgsz* argument to both `msgsnd` and `msgrcv`? This should be the number of bytes to send from, and the maximum number of bytes to receive into, the *mtext* portion of the message structure (neither should exceed `sizeof msg.numero`). See: [`msgop(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/msgop.2.html) for documentation, and an example.

Comment: without shm and put msgget before fork it work but..Why it's not working with shared memory? i want that every chid ha an unique id recognizable by a key_base + a number (ex child 1 id = KeyBase + 1  etc etc).

Comment: @Oka the magic number is only a extrapolation of an example where it is defined as MSG_LEN.

Comment: As is, the call to `msgsnd` will read `N = 120 - sizeof (int)` bytes past the end of the `my_msg` structure and send those bytes in the message. Likewise, the call to `msgrcv` is allowed to write up-to `N` bytes past the end of the `mt_msg` structure. This will invoke [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) by writing outside the bounds of an object. In your examples, the *msgsz* argument should be `sizeof (int)`, or more robustly, `sizeof my_msg.numero`.